# Using Auto Scaling with Code Deploy - Ec2 instances rebooting in a infinite loop

Tags: autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I am using EC2 Auto Scalling together with Code Deploy. As my Code Deployment is falling the launch life-cycle is failling. So the auto scalling is terminating/restarting the ec2 instances in a infinite loop.

The problem is that I can't make a deep troubleshooting as the AutoScalling is Terminating the instance...

How can I avoid the Auto Scalling terminating my EC2 instances? I have already tried to suspend the Terminate process, but as the problem is on Launch Life Cycle, i think it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this behavior before. Taking a look at the system shut off logs after the instances terminate could be a good place to start. Instance Settings > System Log

In my scenario, the system logs had nothing useful to show me. It seemed that regardless of what my user data was doing, eventually after a certain amount of time elapsed, the ASG terminates the spawned instance for no apparent reason.

Through some googling, some people stated that recreating the ASG solved the issue, and fortunately that solved the issue for me as well. The only way I could make sense of how the issue resolved was that during the numerous testing scenarios/configurations/troubleshooting steps I took, some kind of setting got mixed up and only a recreation of the ASG could solve it.